# View de Laravel no actualiza cambios

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo una vista, copiada de otra, y cuando le aplico cambios no se cambia, he puesto la ruta nueva en **routes.php** he limpiado la cache, las vistas, rutas y configuración, e incluso e reiniciado el apache y nada de nada. A que podría ser debido?

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

también he borrado los ficheros de **/storage/framework/views**

Por cierto, en este caso hablo a nivel local, no en producción. Una vez acabada la vista ya haré el deployment.

Answer (score 3):

Aveces me pasa y lo que hago es borrar el historial.

Answer (score 1):

Al final combinando los comandos anteriores y modificando el **php.ini** de la siguiente manera me ha funcionado.

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=0
```