# Action App\Http\Controllers\myController@my_metodo not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Buenos días amigos tengo una ruta en laravel 8 y me dice que no está definida, en mi route.web tengo esto

```
use App\Http\Controllers\myController;


Route::get('mymetodo/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\myController@mymetodo')->name('mymetodo');
```

Después en el controller lo tengo asi:

```
 public function mymetodo($id){
 }

Finalmente el boton está así:
   <a class="btn" target="_blank" href="{{URL::action('App\Http\Controllers\myController@mymetodo',$objeto->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Alguno me podría indicar que cambió en laravel 8 para generar una ruta?, realicé el comando php artisan r:l y no está la ruta

pero si lo invoco así no sale error :

```
<a class="btn" target="_blank" href="{{URL('/mymetodo',[$objeto->id])}}"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

pero la ruta sigue sin estar definida en php artisan r:l que estaré haciendo mal?, sin poder definir la ruta no puedo acceder al método, que problema tendré? hay alguna manera de hacer que el proyecto reconozca una ruta nueva?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que no tienes bien el nombre del método,  en la ruta debería ser algo así:

```
Route::get('/mymetodo/{id}', ['myController::class', 'mymetodo']);
```

Y la definición así:

```
public function mymetodo(Request $request){
    // Para acceder al {$id}
    $request -> id
}
```

También puedes usar estos comandos para poder resetear las rutas:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: No creo que sea eso lo intenté igual, allí edité la pregunta con lo que si me funciona pero a medias

Comment: Vale, acabo de ver tu corrección, lo que haces es invocar al método con la definición, lo cual es incorrecto, tienes que invocar al método como lo has puesto la segunda vez: href="{{URL('/mymetodo',[$objeto->id])}}", pero sin la barra baja "_", por otro lado sigo creyendo que en el "get()" te falta una barra: "/" al inicio.

Comment: cuando me refiero a que funciona es que no sale error pero la ruta sigue sin estar definida en php artisan r:l

Comment: Entiendo, pero no se porque te falla, en Laravel 8 yo defino así las rutas: Route::get('/school/{id}', [SchoolController::class, 'show']); y la implemento así: public function show(Request $request) {}

Comment: si la verdad que no se porque no la toma, así como comentas la puse y he generado rutas, despues de mi modo deseo saber si hay un comando como para que actualice las rutas?

Comment: Échale un vistazo a este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18358/view-de-laravel-no-actualiza-cambios

Comment: me habeis salvado el día llevo toda la mañana con ese tema, lo resolvi con php artisan route:clear, si puedes editar tu respuesta así te califico gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Ya está editado, me alegro que te haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

En Laravel 8, la forma de declarar la ruta es diferente. Se tiene que hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
Route::get('mymetodo/{id}', [myController::class, 'my_metodo'])->name('mymetodo')
```

También parte del problema es que debes llamar a tu ruta desde la vista de la siguiente forma.

```
{{ route('mymetodo', ['id'=>$objeto->id]) }}
```

Comment: No creo que sea eso lo intenté igual, allí edité la pregunta con lo que si me funciona pero a medias